# how to filter object by ManyToManyField in string

Tags: python, django

```py
class User(models.Model):
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Role, through='UserRole', through_fields=('user', 'role'))

class Role(models.Model):
    role_key = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

user = User.objects.filter(roles.name__in='abc')
```

I want to filter user by name of one variable roles.
This does not work, would you please tell me how to do so?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `User.objects.filter(roles__name="abc")`

Have a look at [Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) in the docs.

You also don't need the trailing `__in` in your query, if you want to find users that have the role "abc". On the other hand, if you want to find the users that have the role "abc" or "xyz", you can use it, like this:

`User.objects.filter(roles__name__in=["abc", "xyz"])`

Comment: Got the error:
ValueError: Field 'role_key' expected a number but got 'product lead'.

There are two variable in Role:
class Role(models.Model):
    role_key = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

Comment: It's easier if you also show us the code that causes this error. But it looks like your query might point to `role__key` instead of `role__name`.

Comment: Btw, I updated my answer and removed the trailing `__in` from the query. If you are just looking for users with the role "abc", you don't need it.

Comment: user = User.objects.filter(roles__name='abc')

Comment: Why are you even adding the `role_key` field? [All models automatically get an `id` field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial02/#creating-models).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236382/discussion-between-decibyte-and-minghang).